# has_many through - Notes sender and receiver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm working on a rails app which has three models.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord; end
class Share < ApplicationRecord; end
class Note < ApplicationRecord; end

create_table :users do |t|
  t.timestamps
end

create_table :notes do |t|
      t.integer 'user_id'
      t.text 'title'
      t.text 'short_description'
      t.string 'name'
      t.timestamps
end

create_table :shares do |t|
  t.integer 'user_id'
  t.integer 'receiver_id'
  t.integer 'note_id'
  t.timestamps
end
```

How can I create associations between them so, I can get

- Notes which are shared by User A.
- Notes which are received by User A.
- Notes which are created by User A.

Answer (score 1):

@Mehmet Adil İstikbal gives part of the answer so I'll try to complete it.

This is another way to do it using only associations :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :created_notes, class_name: 'Note', foreign_key: :user_id

  has_many :received_shares, foreign_key: :receiver_id, class_name: 'Share'
  has_many :received_notes, through: :received_shares, source: :note

  has_many :shares
  has_many :shared_notes, through: :shares, source: :note
end

class Share < ApplicationRecord
  # Optional
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id
  belongs_to :receiver, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :receiver_id
  # Mandatory
  belongs_to :note
end

class Note < ApplicationRecord ; end

user_a = User.first
user_a.shared_notes
user_a.received_notes
user_a.created_notes
```

If you choose @Mehmet Adil İstikbal answer, please make sure to transform 
`user.shares.each {|share| share.note}` to `user.shares.map(&:note)` (Use map and not each)

My answer uses has_many through association which allows you to go "through" join table.

Comment: `user_a.received_notes` throws an error `NameError (uninitialized constant User::ReceivedShare)`

Comment: Sorry I forgot the class_name on those lines

Answer (score 0):

In user model you can do like this:

`has_many :shares, foreign_key: 'user_id', class_name: 'Share', dependent: :destroy
 has_many :receives, foreign_key: 'receiver_id', class_name: 'Share', dependent: :destroy`

and you can call like this:

`User.first.shares.each {|share| share.note}`

This will get all shares with first users id and all of their notes.
For receiver :

`User.first.receives.each {|share| share.note}`

In your share model you can also specify the opposite connection like this:

`belongs_to :sender, foreign_key: 'user_id', class_name: 'User'`

`belongs_to :receiver, foreign_key: 'receiver_id', class_name: 'User'`

With this you can call:

`Share.first.receiver` this will get you to user that receives this post

And for the notes which are created by user you can call:

`User.first.notes`

You may want to delete those dependents in order to your project.
Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer let me try and will let you know.